# Dividing Two Functions

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, gm.general-mathematics

I asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2605365/dividing-two-functions) in Math StackExchange originally but haven't received an answer.

When dividing two functions:
$$h(x)=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)},$$

how do we account for the points at which $g(x)=0$ ?

An example is when solving a PDE by separation of variables: Let $\phi(x,y,z)=X(x)Y(y)Z(z)$, then:$$\nabla^2\phi=0\leftrightarrow YZX''+ZXY''+XYZ''=0$$All $\bf {math}$ textbooks, at this step, divide both sides by XYZ, leading to:$$\frac{X''}{X}+\frac{Y''}{Y}+\frac{Z''}{Z}=0$$
But none of them explains why such an operation is valid when there is no requirement for $X,Y,Z$ not to be zeros.

Another example is the Sturm-Liouville equation. In some textbooks, it has the form:$$[p(x)y']'+[q(x)+\lambda r(x)]y=0$$
However, other textbooks divide both sides by $r(x)$ and rearrange the terms to obtain another form (without any justification for the division):$$\frac{1}{r(x)}[(p(x)y')'+q(x)y]+\lambda y=0$$ But we all know that a Sturm-Liouville problem can be singular, which means $r(x)$ could be zero at an endpoint. Obviously, the two forms of Sturm-Liouville equation above are not algebraically equivalent to each other.

Comment: The term "division algebra" belongs to commutative algebra, and it has nothing to do with ratios of functions that you are interested in. At any rate, your question is too broad in my opinion.

Comment: Formally you can do it by discarding the points in the domain where the denominator vanishes. If all the functions involved are meromorphic you can also work in terms of meromorphic functions instead.

Comment: The issue is, in the examples above, we are solving for an unknown function, which means we do not know where it vanishes. But as you can see, while solving differential equations, even in math textbooks, performing function division is done frequently without any justification for the operation.

Comment: @GHfromMO My bad. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: Yes, so you toss out whatever points they end up vanishing at, which is currently unknown to you. As long as there aren’t too many such points this is not a big deal; keep in mind that any two real-analytic functions defined on a connected domain which agree on an open subset of that domain agree identically. The case where the function vanishes identically may need to be considered separately but it’s usually easy to understand.

Comment: On line 3 of your second comment, did you mean they agree identically only on that subset?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the Wikipedia entry for the Sturm-Liouville theory, you will see the following passage:

[image]

You will notice that the vanishing of $r$ ($w$ in the Wikipedia notation) is **explicitly ruled out.** If your source does NOT rule it out, it is being sloppy, and should be flogged with a wet noodle, but this is not a mathematical question. Similarly for the other example - a careful analysis will take care of the various sorts of singularities.

Comment: But a Sturm-Liouville problem can be singular. My concern is that in the case of it being singular, the two forms are not equivalent algebraically, which confuses me a lot because the textbooks that I have use both forms to derive other results.